# Plumbing: Can the drain go down into the floor after the p-trap inside the vanity, or must it go in a wall?

Tags: plumbing

Plumbing: Can the drain go down into the floor after the p-trap inside the vanity, or must it go in a wall?  Are

The drain exits to right side of the vanity, not the back wall of the vanity.

Answer (score 1):

I have plumbed them both ways many homes have the plumbing hidden in the walls but sometimes it is easier to go through the floor so whatever is best for your layout is fine, the only negative of going through the floor is you loose a little storage but this is not much a sacrifice compared to the ease of not having to open the wall and with a small sink it can be much easier to go to the side and down compared to back through the wall and then down.

Comment: What about venting?

Comment: Most bathrooms only have 1 major vent at the toilet with the bath and sink connectedd at the toilet vent lines unless a long distance between them.